# how write serial number of the docx table in python

Tags: python, list, docx, python-docx

i have many inputs and i'd like write they in .docx table with  serial number

```
def write():

    table = doc.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
    table.style = "Table Grid"


    row = table.rows[0].cells
    row[0].text = "name and surname"
    row[1].text = "relative"
    row[2].text = "year of birth"


    for name_surname, relative, year_of_birth in data:
        row = table.add_row().cells
        row[0].text = name_surname
        row[1].text = relative
        row[2].text = year_of_birth
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: i can't to save docx.table  file with serial number

Comment: Does the code in your question work?  Does it create a table?  It should be pretty clear how to modify that to add another column with a row number.

Answer (score 0):

If that code works, then this should do what you want.

```
def write():

    table = doc.add_table(rows=1, cols=4)
    table.style = "Table Grid"


    row = table.rows[0].cells
    row[0].text = "id"
    row[1].text = "name and surname"
    row[2].text = "relative"
    row[3].text = "year of birth"


    for idno, (name_surname, relative, year_of_birth) in enumerate(data):
        row = table.add_row().cells
        row[0].text = str(idno+1)
        row[1].text = name_surname
        row[2].text = relative
        row[3].text = year_of_birth
```